# Designing an App with Sliding Panels

Tags: android, panel, sliding

I'm doing an app for Android, and my idea at first was doing this, but i don't know how to do it:

[image: Idea]

The number of photo panels could vary. What I want to know is which components should I use to implement each part of the activity. If someone could help me, that'd be really nice. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the exact question? We won't write the code for you. If you face issues with the swipe navigation you might learn more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I explained myself the wrong way. All I want is to know the components that I should use to get that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is apply:

- `ScrollView` to your first `Fragment`
- Use `ViewPager` between the image `Fragments`

ScrollView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

ViewPager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Good luck with your app :-)